# Jquery evento click após mudança de atributo

Tags: javascript, jquery, front-end

tenho um probleminha aqui com o Jquery, quando o botão for clicado preciso pegar o valor do input e substituir o atributo 'href' de uma  e ao mesmo tempo clicar nela... não estou tendo resultados, consigo fazer até a parte de substituir o valor do atributo, mas não consigo fazer o evento de click logo após!

btnContatos = botao

contatoParams = input text

enviaContato = Tag A

OBS: isso não é um FORM!

```
$(document).ready( function () {
            $('#btnContatos').click( function () {
                var contato = $('#contatoParams').val()
                //alert(contato)
                $('#enviaContato').attr('href', '/chat/busca/'+contato);

                // Mexer...
            })
        }
```

Comment: Acho que você deveria usar o location.href='/chat/busca/'+contato; Mas, resolvendo a sua pergunta, adicionar trigger não funciona? $('#enviaContato').trigger('click');

Comment: Usar o location deu certo, solução mais fácil do que esperava... agora vem o grosso, configurar os controllers e models... Obrigado amigo!

Comment: Não precisa adicionar "resolvido" no título da pergunta. Você pode adicionar sua própria resposta ou excluir a pergunta.

Comment: Ou aceitar a resposta de alguém.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilizando o JS para chamar a nova página:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btnContatos').click(function(){
        var contato = $('#contatoParams').val();
        location.href = '/chat/busca/' + contato;
    });
});
```